# How can I import variables from a .py file into a list, so that I can use the random module on that list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a python file which includes around 60 lines of variables which are file imports (for pygame). This is the `imports.py` file, it contains only variables,  nothing else. How can I import these into a list in my `main.py`?

**imports.py**

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
one_surf = pygame.image.load("*")

two_surf = pygame.image.load("*")

three_surf = pygame.image.load("*")

four_surf = pygame.image.load("*")

five_surf = pygame.image.load("*")
.
.
.
```

Comment: why not just put all your `imports.py` variables into a list *before* you import it?

Comment: @MZ and then import the list? that sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps slightly rearrange your code like this:

`imports.py`

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

surf = [

  pygame.image.load("*"),

  pygame.image.load("*"),

  pygame.image.load("*"),

  pygame.image.load("*"),

  pygame.image.load("*"),

... ]
```

`something_else.py`

```py
from imports import surf
```

then you can access what was prevously called `three_surf` with `surf[2]`

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary would provide the same functionality as putting variables into a list because you can refer to each image based on a name/value.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

surf = {
    'one_surf': pygame.image.load("*"),
    'two_surf': pygame.image.load("*"),
    'three_surf': pygame.image.load("*"),
    'four_surf': pygame.image.load("*"),
    'five_surf': pygame.image.load("*")
}
```

Storing the information in a dictionary means that you can reference each image based on a key: `surf['one_surf']` holds the same value as the previous `one_surf` variable.